# Использование объекта события при назначении обработчика через addEventListener

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

В учебнике вычитал, что есть несколько способов назначить обработчик события,   но лучше всего через `addEventListener()`.
Ясно, буду использовать `addEventListener()`.
Надо только помнить, что функцию надо писать без скобок.
Написал такую строчку:

```
gameField.addEventListener("click", makeTurn);
```

Дальше узнаю, что есть такой объект события, в котором масса полезной информации. Доступ к нему можно получить:

```
elem.onclick = function(event) {}
```

Но я то делаю через `addEventListener()`!

Так вот, могу ли я получить доступ к объекту события (а мне надо),
если напишу функцию `function makeTurn(event) {}` ?

Comment: Да.... Именно так...  Кстати, а что тебе мешало самому попробовать методом тыка????

Comment: спасибо! а почему ты спрашиваешь?

Comment: Просто стало интересно...

Comment: собственно поэкспериментировал)

Comment: upButton.addEventListener("click", funk);

let event = [1, 2];

function funk(event) {
alert(event.clientX + ":" + event.clientY);
}

что интересно, явное объявление event не меняет работы функции, но и ошибки никакой не выдает

Comment: а вот такой код выдает два разных сообщения:
`upButton.addEventListener("click", funk);

let event = [1, 2];

function funk(event) {
alert(event.clientX + ":" + event.clientY);
alert(event);
}
alert(event);`

Comment: нет там ни какой ошибки, потому и не выдает ошибку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наличие параметра `event` не определяется способом создания обработчика.

Так как в итоге, где-то внутри, при событии обработчик вызывается следующим образом:

```
var event = new Event(); // создается объект события
handler(event); // объект события передается в непосредственный обработчик
```

Следовательно, нет разницы был ли обработчик навешан так

```
elem.onclick = handler;
```

или так

```
elem.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

В обоих случаях в метод handler будет передан параметр `event`.

Это так же не зависит от объявления самой функции `handler`:

```
handler () {...}
handler (event) {...}
handler (e) {...}
```

Во всех случаях будет передан этот параметр. Проверить это можно с помощью объекта `arguments`, в котором хранятся фактически переданные параметры.

Comment: Ваш ответ помог мне решить задачу:) Спасибо!